# jQuery resize window object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can I manually resize the window object in jQuery? I'm modifying a web application on iPhone which has window width 640px and I don't know how it can be cause iPhone screen is 320px wide (portrait mode).
I tried to remove all meta tags from the head section of the HTML document but nothing changed.
Any idea of how I can solve this?

---

I had no success with additional meta tags. The main problem is that iPhone 4 has a `640x960 px` screen. I didn't know this before. So my media query for iPhone was set to `320x480 px`.
But there is another problem. When I switch the mode, the resolution goes to `320x480 px` and it stays on these values.
I don't know why is this happening and it's very hard to set CSS for this situation.

The client has both meta tags on their site, I don't know why:

```
"meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5, minimum-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=1.0"
"meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width"
```

Comment: You sure this isn't a scaling issue with css, or viewport? 
Have this in your head?  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />  Reference - http://eisabainyo.net/weblog/2009/06/12/making-a-website-iphone-friendly-using-css/

Comment: `cause iPhone screen is 320px wide`. It depends, iPhone 4 has actually a 640x960px screen.

Comment: Yeah right. That's what is killing me. But when I switch the mode the resolution goes to 320x480 px. I'm alerting window height on orientation change. Is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

Is the following in your document `<head>`?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This will prevent ios from scaling the page.

After that, you will have to resize/shift the contents of the application to match the device, not the other way around.

CSS [Media Queries](http://cssmediaqueries.com/what-are-css-media-queries.html) will be a great help in adapting your webApp to a mobile format.